# getting error in angular project in the import statement

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular. I am having an issue calling a type script module in different folder. I have the following structure in my angular project. My angular project and my .net core project exists in the same application. Below is the image:

[image]

whenever I am calling my type script class that exists inside models folder from any other folder, I get an error saying "cannot found module 'src/modules/acrDivison' so for e.g. if I call acrDivison.ts that exists inside models from add-project/add-project.componet.ts  by the below statement

import { AcrDivison } from 'src/models/acrDivison';

then I get an error saying "cannot found module 'src/modules/acrDivison'.

any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move up two steps to be in src directory then write the dir to the AcrDivision module

```
import { AcrDivison } from '../../models/acrDivison';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what your component have this:

`export class AcrDivison implements OnInit { }`